# Resize ListView when column becomes smaller

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a listview and when I manual resize the column width the whole listview becomes bigger, so far so good. But when I downsize the column the listview stil stays the width is was. Is it posible that the listview also downsizes with the column width?

Here is a simple example of the situation:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data">
                <x:XData>
                    <Data xmlns="">
                        <Item ID="1"/>
                        <Item ID="2"/>
                        <Item ID="3"/>
                    </Data>
                </x:XData>
            </XmlDataProvider>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ListView DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}, XPath=/Data}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Item}" SelectionMode="Single">                  
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

            <TextBlock Text="Test" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, well it's not really the best maybe but it works for me. I added a gridsplitter between the columns and set the columns width to *.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data">
                <x:XData>
                    <Data xmlns="">
                        <Item ID="1"/>
                        <Item ID="2"/>
                        <Item ID="3"/>
                    </Data>
                </x:XData>
            </XmlDataProvider>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ListView DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}, XPath=/Data}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Item}" SelectionMode="Single">                  
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>


            <TextBlock Text="Test" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```